# Javascript doesn't work on ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm using Youtube Iframe API and using their script the player loads fine. But when I do an ajax call to the php file containing javascript code to run the player, it doesn't execute.

```
function get_content(song_id,url,song_title) {
if (song_id == null)
    return;
    document.title = song_title + browser_title_suffix;
    $.get('/ajax/player.php',{song_id:song_id}, function(data) {
        $('#main_content').html(data).css({'opacity':0}).animate({'opacity':1});
        });
        }
```

/ajax/player.php contains this code - https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player

However, the player does not again. I even tried player.remove() but that didn't help either.

**UPDATE 1:**
My PHP file:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

$(document).ready(function(){
get_content('.$row[song_id].',null,"'.$row[title].'");
});

</script>
```

My javascript file:

```
function get_content(song_id,url,song_title) {
if (song_id != null) {
    $.get('/ajax/player.php',{song_id:song_id}, function(data) {
        video_id = data;
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            videoId: video_id,
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    });

}
}
```

**However, the video player does not load.**

Comment: Anything in he console? Does the PHP loaded directly show the correct data?

Comment: No, nothing in the console and when php loads the data the first time, it all works fine. It's when I want to load new content that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get javascript via ajax and then run the just recieved javascript. What you want to do is just send the youtube video id via ajax and then use a function like this to place the player:

```
function get_content(song_id,url,song_title) {
    if (song_id != null) {
        $.get('/ajax/player.php',{song_id:song_id}, function(data) {
            video_id = data;

            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '390',
                width: '640',
                videoId: video_id,
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Better yet, try JSON to send and recieve data via Jquery.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. I followed your suggestion but it is not triggering the player to load. I have posted the update under **UPDATE 1** I get the following error in console: Uncaught ReferenceError: YT is not defined

Comment: Well, so make sure that it IS defined since you use it... not enough code for us to help further.